# How can I select one of two objects depending if one is null or not with a LinQ to Entities query.

Tags: c#, sql-server, linq, entity-framework

```
List<IStoreItem> StoreItems = new List<IStoreItem>();             

StoreItems = repository.ProductToCatMaps.Where(x => CatList.Contains(x.ExCatID))
             .Select(x => x.ProductShell ?? x.PCBuild);
```

The entity classes:

```
    public class ProductShell : IStoreItem
    {
    }

    public class PCBuild : IStoreItem
    {
    }
```

The ProductToCatMaps table contains the external category ID for each
respective store item, I have two store items types: ProductShell and PCBuild.
I wish to select either one depending on which is set to null, only one
can contain a value (Foregn key to the respective types entry in the database ) which I need to select.

Comment: Try `.Select(x => (IStoreItem)x.ProductShell ?? x.PCBuild);` - it might work, but I am not sure that it would.

Comment: You don't need to initialize StorItems to an empty list, when you reassign it to the repository result right after.

Answer (score 3):

The translation of your *intent* to SQL is going to be nigh impossible (or perhaps just improbable*), because the SQL to get the ProductShell fully populated is going to be wholly different than the sql to get PCBuild. I would switch directions and do the last bit of your query in memory. Something like

```
StoreItems = repository.ProductToCatMaps
                       .Where(yourCondition)
                       .Select(x => new { x.ProductShell, x.PCBuild })
                       .AsEnumerable() // *** pulls above into memory
                       .Select(x => (IStoreItem)x.ProductShell ?? (IStoreItem)x.PCBuild);
```

---

*Of course, I haven't tried your approach at home, so if it does in fact work (with some modification, I assume that by asking, what you have so far doesn't function), then kudos to the EF team.